# TeX capacity exceeded with listings package

Tags: listings

In trying to find the source of the following error in my LaTeX document, the `listings` package seems to not be runnable

The minimal example, which I implied but did not include was:

```
\documentclass[10pt][article]
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

The error is

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian) (format=latex 2014.5.13)  20 OCT 2014    13:19                                             
entering extended mode                                                                                                                                       
 restricted \write18 enabled.                                                                                                                                  
 %&-line parsing  enabled.                                                                                                                                    
 **alfresco_documentation.tex                                                                                                                                 

(./alfresco_documentation.tex                                                                                                                                
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>                                                                                                                                         
Babel <3.9h> and hyphenation patterns for 2 languages loaded.                                                                                                
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=10000].                                                                                                 
\@fileswithoptions #1->                                                                                                                                      
                   \@ifnextchar [{\@fileswith@ptions #1}{\@fileswith@pti...                                                                              
l.2 \usepackage{                                                                                                                                             
            listings}
If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
5 strings out of 495029
193 string characters out of 6181523
114383 words of memory out of 5000000
 3315 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 4289i,0n,10001p,52b,8s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
No pages of output.
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Please consider adding a minimal working example to your question. Without it, you are making it really harder (if not impossible) for people here to provide an answer to your problem.

Comment: what do you mean by "empty" here? The file must have content (as the error is reported on line 2 ?

Comment: @close-voters: This question is just 22min 'old' and there are about 3 votes for closing it. It might be unclear, but there is still some time left for the OP to clearify it

Comment: @close voters: please allow time for David to improve his question. It's been only 20 min!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can reproduce the problem when the document class is specified in brackets `[...]` instead of braces `{...}`.

```
\documentclass[article]
\usepackage{listings}
```

The terminal shows

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./bosh.tex
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=10000].
\@fileswithoptions #1->
                       \@ifnextchar [{\@fileswith@ptions #1}{\@fileswith@pti...
l.2 \usepackage{
                listings}
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Also

```
\documentclass
\usepackage{listings}
```

produces the same error.

Of course it should be

```
\documentclass{article} % or any other class
\usepackage{listings}
```

Comment: Perhaps emphasise that the difference between the working and non-working examples is in the brackets/braces of the `documentclass` call. It's not that obvious...